# how to get the unselected criteria in AutoFilter Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel 2007 with VBA
We have a table. The user has filtered column 5 to certain items. I know I can get the currently selected criteria using:

```
'set table
Dim loStats As ListObject
Set loStats = ws.ListObjects("TableStats")

'get filter list
Dim af5 As Variant
af5 = loStats.AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1

'print
Dim x As Integer
For x = LBound(af5) To UBound(af5)
    Debug.Print af5(x)
Next
```

But what about when the user has cleared the filter from column 5. This doesn't work after the user has cleared the filter in column 5

```
af5 = loStats.AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1
```

How do I get the list of possible criteria like the user sees in the dropdown box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So, where do I start?**

Firstly, you falsely assume that the result will be an array. If I choose only one value, then `LBound(af5)` will return a type mismatch error. You can correct it with

```
If IsArray(Arr) Then
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
    Next
Else
    Debug.Print Arr
End If
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't solve anything. Your procedure prints out not the currently filtered items, but the criteria chosen by the user. This will be misleading.

Consider a table with two columns. When the user specifies criteria as `>3` the result that you will see is `>3`. What does it actually tell you about the values which are filtered? You don't know how many (if any) were chosen and which ones they are. For example, the second column could store {1, 2, 3}, but also {3, 7, 99}.

This is the way I would do it:

```
Sub PrintOutFilteredData()
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Dim CellCount As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    On Error Resume Next
    CellCount = Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Debug.Print "All data was filtered out"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each Cell In Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If IsEmpty(Arr(0)) Then
            ReDim Arr(0 To 0)
            Arr(0) = Cell.Value
        Else
            ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To UBound(Arr) + 1)
            Arr(UBound(Arr)) = Cell.Value
        End If
    Next Cell

    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The use of `On Error Resume Next` prevents the procedure from throwing an error when there are no cells left visible, prints out a message and exits the procedure.

Comment: OK so I guess I need to figure out a way to get only unique values yet.

Comment: @D_Bester Try using collection.

Comment: This is a great start but I ended up dumping the 1 column range to a 1D array using `transpose`; then I put the array to a collection to get only unique values; finally I put the collection into another 1D array for use later.

Comment: I'm actually using the entire DataBodyRange.Columns(5), not only the visible range since want ALL the possible values.

Comment: "This will be misleading." I changed my title to say criteria instead of items as what I really want to know is what criteria the user has selected and what they have left unselected.